# URL Parameters are passed as null instead of what is expected to pass

Tags: api, amazon-dynamodb

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3dZCM9i0Ss) on creating my first DynamoDb along with his github code. I added three fields to the database, title, creator, and body.  When I pass them on in the GET url as

```
https://localhost:44317/api/dynamodb/putitems?id=4&replyDateTime=63668789020007900&body=ilovelife&title=mytittle&creator=me
```

it is placed in the database as:

```
        {
            "id": 4,
            "replyDateTime": "63668789020007900",
            "body": null,
            "title": null,
            "creator": null
        },
```

This is the C# code where I add the fields:

```
private PutItemRequest RequestBuilder(int id, string replyDateTime, string body, string title, string creator)
        {
            var item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
            {
                {"Id", new AttributeValue {N = id.ToString()}},
                {"ReplyDateTime", new AttributeValue {N = replyDateTime}},
                {"Body", new AttributeValue {S = body}},
                 {"Creator", new AttributeValue {S = creator}},
                  {"Title", new AttributeValue {S = title}}
            };

            return new PutItemRequest
            {
                TableName = "BlogDynamoDbTable",
                Item = item
            };
```

The values in Item are sent to the database but end up being null:

[image]

Comment: Seems like you asked the same question here: [Putitem in DynamoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686566/putitem-in-dynamodb). Can you improve the other question instead, make it clearer, and close this one?

Comment: @tugberk Thanks, I did not realize I had finished posting the other question. I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the API code as a POST instead of a GET. The JSON data works after adding another nuget package for json reading for NET 3.0